# Propagation delay from moving magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

If you have a magnet moving according to some velocity with a given magnetic field how do you compute the field at a given time given the propagation delay?

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations? This starts with a current as the source of the magnetic field, but that's a much easier problem than having to calculate the magnetic field of a permanent magnetic material.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd just perform a Lorentz transform from the stationary frame. That seems like the easiest route to solving this sort of problem. Just don't neglect to account for the retarded time for the propagation delay.